# Is it possible to connect to VisualSVN server throught internet

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Is it possible to connect to VisualSVN server throught internet? 
Please help i am stuck with it

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this is the wrong site to ask on. You probably have a network setup problem (e.g. a router not letting traffic through.) Voting to migrate to serverfault.com

Comment: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may connect to a VisualSVN instance over the internet, assuming your server and firewall(s) (if applicable) accepts incoming connections from the internet on the port your VisualSVN instance is running. You can connect with any of the usual protocols, including svn, http, https, etc.

See the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started documentation](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/); the end of it describes how to test your connection.